# Spring Integration support for non-conforming services

Tags: spring-integration

Spring-WS provides the following support as part of their template.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#setCheckConnectionForFault(boolean)

Trying to determine if Spring Integration exposes this.  Found the following from 2012, however I was hoping it would be part of the framework.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/119981-ws-outbound-gateway-and-soap-fault

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't support yet.

As I said there: feel free to raise a JIRA issue! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Example configuration based on explanation from 2012 link ...

```
@Bean
@Description("Workaround for non conforming services")
AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway initializeWebserviceGateway(
        @Qualifier("wsOutboundGateway.handler") Object bean) {

    Advised advised = (Advised) bean;

    AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway gateway = null;
    try {
        gateway = (AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway) advised
                .getTargetSource().getTarget();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to configure webServiceTemplate for non conforming services");
    } 

    DirectFieldAccessor dfa = new DirectFieldAccessor(gateway);
    WebServiceTemplate wst = (WebServiceTemplate) dfa
            .getPropertyValue("webServiceTemplate");
    wst.setCheckConnectionForError(false);
    wst.setCheckConnectionForFault(false);

    return gateway;
}
```